# Animate object using android accelerometer data

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, python, css

I am using an Android app to stream accelerometer data to a python script on my PC, which is then written to a text file. I am then attempting to use Javascript and jQuery to animate a 3d CSS cuboid (in the shape of a device) to mimic how the device moved when streaming the data.

[image]

At first I tried this using the gyroscope data, which is outputted in radians/s. I converted this to degrees/s by multiplying the value by 57 (one radian in degs) or so, but when I tried to `rotateX: 100deg` for instance this resulted in erratic behaviour when using these values to animate.

I would like to know how I can animate a 3d CSS object using data gathered from my android device's accelerometer, or whether this is possible at all?

Comment: can you post the data that you gathered from the gyroscope ?

Comment: please post some part of your current animation-code and also mention what other thing have you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API), you will find much of what you need in its API(for 3D transformation and rendering of the phone object in browser).
Also, as [user1561358](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34482370/1329429) suggests cut the middle man, why are you using a python script to relay data when you can open a websocket from the js to your android app. This will also save you from constantly polling the file.

> I would like a full explanation to my problem.

1. Android application creates a socket on launchtime, informs the user of its ip and port.
2. webgl app asks for the ip:port information, upon submit opens the websocket.
3. if the handshake is successful asks user to stabilize the phone and sync both ends(presses a button so that phone will inform the WebGL that it is perfectly horizontal.)
4. from sync on, phone will relay any changes in 3 axes to the WebGL app thru the socket.
5. WebGL transforms the phone object according to received changes of phone orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Few things come to mind.

1. Convert radians to degrees by Python function `math.degrees(x)`
2. How did you set up the reference frame? The fact that device rotates is not enough by itself. You also need to know in relation to what it is turning.
3. Cut the middle man. More languages and conversions you use the more complicated the problem gets. It is much easier to overlook things. Consider writing the app in just one language and skipping the text file.

EDIT: This would be better as a comment because it is not a definite answer. Unfortunately I lack necessary privileges.